# How do I calculate ages in postgresql with only their yearborn (will be an estimate) - specifically want to get the youngest person and their age

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE people (
id integer NOT NULL,
name text NOT NULL,
year_born public.yeartype,
year_died public.yeartype
```

I know there is a formula that uses age(birthdate) but what if i only have the year?

Comment: You want to know how long they lived? Or how old they were if the didn't die now? Or only how old the still living are? And cannot you use a surrogate month and day like 01-01, 07-03 or 12-31?

Comment: @stickybit the only age I really need is the age of the youngest person in the database. Id like to avoid using a surrogate month and day if I can.

Comment: what is a `public.yeartype`? what does the data look like, just  a 4 digit year?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Yes exactly e.g. 1996

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you perhaps

```
select round(((current_date - to_date('2000','yyyy'))  / 365.25)-1,0)

result: 20
```

Assuming you `public.yeartype` can be changed to text, then perhaps this will do:

```
select round(((current_date - to_date(year_born::text,'yyyy'))  / 365.25)-1,0)
where year_died IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You've two information facets: year_born and year_died but it isn't clear whether you're looking for youngest person still alive or youngest age reached by a person irrespective of living status.  Either way there may be collisions (ie. multiple people born in the same year and lack of precision in measuring against a given year_born.  You might consume the first matching record returned (possibly influenced by additional criteria) or consume a list of collisions.

**Note:** for both cases, transform year_born and year_died to timestamps and use extract with them or if not feasible then normalize year_born and year_died with the extract(year from now()) result, casting to double.

**return youngest alive person/people**

```
select 
  name,
  (extract(year from now()) 
    - extract(year from year_born::timestamp)) as age

from people
-- where some other filter criteria 
order by age  -- put our youngest person/people at the top
limit 1       -- return only the top most row .. remove to return 
              -- all colliding 'youngest' ages
;
```

**return person/people, alive or dead, with shortest age**

```
select 
  name,
  (case
    when year_died is null then -- use this year
      (extract(year from now()) - extract(year from year_born::timestamp))  
    else -- use the year_died
      (extract(year from year_died::timestamp) - extract(year from year_born::timestamp))
    end) as age

from people
-- where some other filter criteria 
order by age  -- put our youngest person/people at the top
limit 1       -- return only the top most row .. remove to return 
              -- all colliding 'youngest' ages
;
```